# Check if YouTube Channel is Live Streaming

Tags: vb.net, request, httprequest, youtube-data-api, httpresponse

I'm trying to build a VB.net site to display an image next to a channel name if it is live streaming. I have the page currently built out holding URLs and the images and I have the search API set up:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[ChannelID]&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API-KEY]

I know this is working because I see the JSON when following the link normally.

The only problem is that I don't know how to send an HTTP request in VB. I was going to just execute this request on page_load while testing, but this is as far as  I've gotten:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[ChannelID]&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API-KEY]")
End Sub
```

How can I send this request in VB.net? How would I read the JSON returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the `JSON` returned into a `String` variable:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[ChannelID]&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API-KEY]")
    Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

    Dim youtube As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd

    MsgBox(youtube)
End Sub
```

I have modified this into a function to allow checking against any channel ID. It originally returned a `boolean`, but I adjusted it to return an `integer` to perform error handling without needing to modify the return statements or handling of the function calls in other sections of the code behind.

```
Protected Function IsLiveStreaming(channelID As String) As Integer

    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=" & channelID & "&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API-KEY]")

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse

        Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim youtube As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd

        Dim obj As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = JObject.Parse(youtube)
        Dim arr As JArray = obj("items")

        If arr.Count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Typically a 403 error from exceeding quota on YouTube api
        Return -1
    End Try

    Return False

End Function
```